# Make WordPress Search Block only show results of child pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added in a my WordPress website a search block like this:

```
<!-- wp:search {"label":"","placeholder":"Find in Help Center","buttonText":"Search"} /-->
```

When the user uses it, it searches all the pages on my website. However, I would like it to be so that the search results only show results from child pages.

E.g.
If I add the search block on the page `.../help-center/`, I only want it to search the child pages of `help-center`.

I have added this to my `searchform.php`

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php
    global $post;
    $ancestors2 = $post->ancestors;
    if ($ancestors2) {
        echo end($ancestors2);
    } else {
        echo $post->ID;
    } ?>" name="post_parent" />
```

and this to `functions.php`

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
        if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s']) && !empty($_GET['post_parent'])) {
            $parent_page_id = intval($_GET['post_parent']);
            $query->set('post_parent', $parent_page_id );
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

This makes it only to search child pages, but only works for my main search bar on the page.

Instead, I would want my main search bar to search the whole page as it is by default, but my `wp:search` block to only search child pages.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

see if inserting the following function to your `functions.php` file and blocking adult pages works

```
// Remove pages from search results
function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_search() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
 {
     return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search' );
```